Jenkins validation error Delete is not a standard action and cannot be overridden
I have made some changes in 2 permission sets and removed some fields read permissions.
Pushed the changes in my branch.
Now when I try to run validation build in Jenkins, I get error like below:
14:11:43  [1m[31mComponent Failures [1][39m[22m
14:11:43  ==========================================================================================
14:11:43  [1m| Type  Name         Problem                                                   Line:Column [22m
14:11:43  [1m| ───── ──────────── ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────── ─────────── [22m
14:11:43  | Error EmailMessage Delete is not a standard action and cannot be overridden.

 

I verified in the targe org also:

But we have not made any change in the EmailMessage object in the branch.
Is anybody aware what can be reason for such issue?

I also started to have this error returned during a deployment. Sometimes salesforce doing changes in patches and modifies metadata of objects/flows etc.
Just pull this object from your org and commit those changes.
In my case, the following lines have been removed from EmailMessage.object metadata.
<actionOverrides>
    <actionName>Delete</actionName>
    <type>Default</type>
</actionOverrides>
<actionOverrides>
    <actionName>Delete</actionName>
    <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
    <type>Default</type>
</actionOverrides>
<actionOverrides>
    <actionName>Delete</actionName>
    <formFactor>Small</formFactor>
    <type>Default</type>
</actionOverrides>


Thanks. But I am able to see the Delete button in our production org. We will add the compoent in forceignore and proceed.

This also fixed the issue for my team. वरुण, the issue is likely that these default actionOverrides used to exist in the metadata markup by default. I'm assuming these are placeholders and there's no way to actually override the delete action. Some sort of patch updated the metadata to reflect this. You can verify it by retrieving the EmailMessage.object-meta.xml file from your org. You'll see these overrides disappear after last night's/yesterday's update

We also ran into this in our sandboxes. All of our validations and deployments are failing until we remove the offending XML from our repo. We'll need to keep an eye on our next prod deployment, though, and possibly put them back into our release branch since those default actions are still in our prod org.
